# Any Java API in Azure to get existing ServiceBusContract?

Tags: java, azure

I am using the tutorial [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/) for pushing data and consuming, data from Azure Service Bus. When I run the example the second time, I get back an error PUT https://asbtest.servicebus.windows.net/TestQueue?api-version=2012-08 returned a response status of 409 Conflict, which is way of saying you have already a configuration with that name, so do not create it another time. Most probably, this is the guilty code

```
Configuration config = 
ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithWrapAuthentication(
  "HowToSample",
  "your_service_bus_owner",
  "your_service_bus_key",
  ".servicebus.windows.net",
  "-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9");

ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
QueueInfo queueInfo = new QueueInfo("TestQueue");
```

That is recalling create() is causing the problem, I would guess. But all methods in com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.ServiceBusService from http://dl.windowsazure.com/javadoc/ are only create, and I am unable to find a method like

```
ServiceBusContract service = A_class_that_finds_existing_bus_contract.find(config);
```

Am I thinking the wrong way, or is there another way out. Any pointers are appreciated.

EDIT:

I realized my code example for what I was asking was config, not service bus contract. Updated it, to reflect so.

Comment: No, 409 conflict means there is already a queue of the same name. It has nothing to do with the service or config.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was wrong. The create() function in ServiceBusService does not throw any exception, as I gathered from Javadocs. Also, you can create the service bus contracts multiple times, as it being only a connection. The exception arises, when you attempt to create a queue with a name that already exists. That is this line.

```
String path = "TestQueue";
QueueInfo queueInfo = new QueueInfo(path);
```

To overcome this, you can go this way.

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.Util;
...
...
Iterable<QueueInfo> iqnf = Util.iterateQueues(service);
boolean queue_created = false;
for( QueueInfo qi : iqnf )
{
  if( path.toLowerCase().equals( qi.getPath() )) 
  {
    System.out.println(" Queue already exists. Do not create one.");
    queue_created = true;
  }
}
if ( !queue_created ) {
  service.createQueue(queueInfo);
}
```

Hope, this helps anybody who may be stuck on create conflicts for queue on Azure.

EDIT: Even after I got the path code, my code refused to work. Turns out there is another caveat. Azure makes all queue names in lower case. I have edited the code to use toLower() for this work around.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Soham's Question and Answer. I did not know about lowercase though I have not verified it. It did confirm the problem I am having right now as well.

The way @Soham has addressed it is good but not good for large ServicebUs where we may have tons of Queues it's added overhead to iterate it. The only way is to catch the ServiceException which is very generic and ignore that Exception.

Example:

```
QueueInfo queueInfo = new QueueInfo(queName);
        try {
            CreateQueueResult qr = service.createQueue(queueInfo);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
          //Silently ignore for now. 
        }
```

The right way would be for the Azure library to extend the ServiceException and `throw "ConcflictException"` for e.g. which is present in `httpStatusCode` of `ServiceException` but unfortunately it's set to Private.

Since it is not We would have to extend the ServiceException and override the httpStatusCode setter.

Again, not the best way but the library can improve if we list as feedback on their Github issues.

Note: ServiceBus is still in preview phase.